# UTXO are not being listed while they have conf over 100 (btcd + simnet)

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind

I am using BTCD and while in Simnet, I generated 104 block (Best block : 104)
But when I listed utxos, transaction from block 3 and 4 (which have 102 and 101 confirmations) don't be listed. So balance shown only 50 btc that is reward of 5. block. You can see console outputs below.

```
PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet listunspent
[]

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet getblockhash 3
5d59b05643d0c058d1b9839db3629b8a794b8617a970d5f23e45d5891efa3f35

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet getblock 5d59b05643d0c058d1b9839db3629b8a794b8617a970d5f23e45d5891efa3f35
{
  "hash": "5d59b05643d0c058d1b9839db3629b8a794b8617a970d5f23e45d5891efa3f35",
  "confirmations": 100,
  "strippedsize": 188,
  "size": 188,
  "weight": 752,
  "height": 3,
  "version": 536870912,
  "versionHex": "20000000",
  "merkleroot": "0921fead5a3b0747ced64a18c03a0b1fafc5fecabf06fff4d523176b5754b82a",
  "tx": [
    "0921fead5a3b0747ced64a18c03a0b1fafc5fecabf06fff4d523176b5754b82a"
  ],
  "time": 1539433120,
  "nonce": 2,
  "bits": "207fffff",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "previousblockhash": "1641c6a0d5916cfc2f70b7c89fcd27dfb85fe11886516dc6f1de36b8f4761212",
  "nextblockhash": "3bc06d8a82d93c3a8839288f56d949bb047dfbd597b39c6f62cf1f6da47d1692"
}

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet gettransaction 0921fead5a3b0747ced64a18c03a0b1fafc5fecabf06fff4d523176b5754b82a
-5: No information for transaction

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet getbalance
0

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf generate 1
[
  "37169e2ff42e2900394ca526ce675444e0d074dc03839c70aa81bf03b845fc84"
]

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet getbalance
50

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet getblockhash 3
5d59b05643d0c058d1b9839db3629b8a794b8617a970d5f23e45d5891efa3f35

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet getblock 5d59b05643d0c058d1b9839db3629b8a794b8617a970d5f23e45d5891efa3f35
{
  "hash": "5d59b05643d0c058d1b9839db3629b8a794b8617a970d5f23e45d5891efa3f35",
  "confirmations": 102,
  "strippedsize": 188,
  "size": 188,
  "weight": 752,
  "height": 3,
  "version": 536870912,
  "versionHex": "20000000",
  "merkleroot": "0921fead5a3b0747ced64a18c03a0b1fafc5fecabf06fff4d523176b5754b82a",
  "tx": [
    "0921fead5a3b0747ced64a18c03a0b1fafc5fecabf06fff4d523176b5754b82a"
  ],
  "time": 1539433120,
  "nonce": 2,
  "bits": "207fffff",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "previousblockhash": "1641c6a0d5916cfc2f70b7c89fcd27dfb85fe11886516dc6f1de36b8f4761212",
  "nextblockhash": "3bc06d8a82d93c3a8839288f56d949bb047dfbd597b39c6f62cf1f6da47d1692"
}

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet getblockhash 4
3bc06d8a82d93c3a8839288f56d949bb047dfbd597b39c6f62cf1f6da47d1692

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet getblock 3bc06d8a82d93c3a8839288f56d949bb047dfbd597b39c6f62cf1f6da47d1692
{
  "hash": "3bc06d8a82d93c3a8839288f56d949bb047dfbd597b39c6f62cf1f6da47d1692",
  "confirmations": 101,
  "strippedsize": 188,
  "size": 188,
  "weight": 752,
  "height": 4,
  "version": 536870912,
  "versionHex": "20000000",
  "merkleroot": "77ddf342bf332d2aa29269e75bb8464e853c2eef4936b7ab60a29192c4132874",
  "tx": [
    "77ddf342bf332d2aa29269e75bb8464e853c2eef4936b7ab60a29192c4132874"
  ],
  "time": 1539433121,
  "nonce": 2,
  "bits": "207fffff",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "previousblockhash": "5d59b05643d0c058d1b9839db3629b8a794b8617a970d5f23e45d5891efa3f35",
  "nextblockhash": "32b72487f4f9473952db6474a999b21aa31df353daf7a66199eb6f5e58adb03e"
}

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet getblockhash 5
32b72487f4f9473952db6474a999b21aa31df353daf7a66199eb6f5e58adb03e

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet getblock 32b72487f4f9473952db6474a999b21aa31df353daf7a66199eb6f5e58adb03e
{
  "hash": "32b72487f4f9473952db6474a999b21aa31df353daf7a66199eb6f5e58adb03e",
  "confirmations": 100,
  "strippedsize": 187,
  "size": 187,
  "weight": 748,
  "height": 5,
  "version": 536870912,
  "versionHex": "20000000",
  "merkleroot": "b09fd1f23884ff6e64213604ae7c385b3d3a3ddc47fb5536816800df5e782c5a",
  "tx": [
    "b09fd1f23884ff6e64213604ae7c385b3d3a3ddc47fb5536816800df5e782c5a"
  ],
  "time": 1539433121,
  "nonce": 0,
  "bits": "207fffff",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "previousblockhash": "3bc06d8a82d93c3a8839288f56d949bb047dfbd597b39c6f62cf1f6da47d1692",
  "nextblockhash": "6179c9823f4614f5255727576b955a6a4f1340706329eac314f08c55da947d98"
}

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet listunspent
[
  {
    "txid": "b09fd1f23884ff6e64213604ae7c385b3d3a3ddc47fb5536816800df5e782c5a",
    "vout": 0,
    "address": "SYYFCKLX38x6aZRsxuLmdNXSBDZ3BaJczq",
    "account": "default",
    "scriptPubKey": "76a9147b5b07b286ef494549db8630aeb37301bf99663c88ac",
    "amount": 50,
    "confirmations": 100,
    "spendable": true
  }
]

PS D:\Blockchain\bitcoin\node> btcctl -C .\btcctl.conf --wallet getbestblock
{
   "hash": "37169e2ff42e2900394ca526ce675444e0d074dc03839c70aa81bf03b845fc84",
   "height": 104
}
```